# SHA1 different between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, sha1

Hi i'm porting a c++ program to C# but the sha result are different.
I'm using openssl library with a wrapper for c#

I have this codes

C++

```
BigNumber A;
A.SetHexStr("4C9309B98E8A3D7E357688305FECFA1676404D0ABFDE0AB48A98EF318AAE35EA");
SHA1Hash sha;
sha.UpdateBigNumbers(&A);
sha.Finalize();
BigNumber u;
u.SetBinary(sha.GetDigest(), 20);
log("u: %d %s", u.GetNumBytes(), u.AsHexStr());
```

Result

```
A: 4C9309B98E8A3D7E357688305FECFA1676404D0ABFDE0AB48A98EF318AAE35EA    
u: 330E234D38088E7C58B40A278A0833B844F06CB5
```

Here is the link for SHA1Hash.cpp
http://pastebin.com/hf5mn1zU

C#

```
  Sha1Hash SHA = new Sha1Hash();

  byte[] digest = new byte[20];
  BigNumber A = BigNumber.FromHexString("4C9309B98E8A3D7E357688305FECFA1676404D0ABFDE0AB48A98EF318AAE35EA");
  SHA.UpdateData(A.ToBytes(),A.Bytes);
  SHA.Final();
  BigNumber u = BigNumber.FromArray(SHA.getDigest(), 20);
  Logger.Message(LogLevel.Debug, A.ToHexString());
  Logger.Message(LogLevel.Debug, u.ToHexString());
```

Result

```
A 4C9309B98E8A3D7E357688305FECFA1676404D0ABFDE0AB48A98EF318AAE35EA
u 1085A72DE27D6D981C1382170B6E39FDED45B92D
```

C# Files

http://pastebin.com/yCHMkaZS

I tried everything encoding etc but i don't know why they don't match

Thanks in advance

Update:
No it still don't work even with NULL

Comment: I'd recommend you to translate your C++ code to equivalent official C# code and not to a 3rd party library code (there is not C# Sha1Hash class as far as I know and your code does not list its source so I guess it is a 3rd party library) - just because it has similar interface. Managed SHA1 implementation created/verified by Microsoft is available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha1managed.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I used these classes and now the hashs match

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class

https://github.com/justMaku/mClient/blob/master/mClient/Crypt/Sha1Hash.cs

Answer (score 4):

The C# version is correct. I'm assuming this [documentation](http://www.trinitycore.net/d6/da6/classSHA1Hash.html#ab1a46b2a0f1a20b2af0643a32f91d757)  corresponds to your library.

This:

```
sha.UpdateBigNumbers(&A);
```

should be

```
sha.UpdateBigNumbers(&A, NULL);
```

since `SHA1Hash::updateBigNumbers` is a variadic function that accepts a `NULL`-terminated list of arguments. You fail to provide the sentinel value, so the function has undefined behavior.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow but if I remember correctly I've already tried this and the c++ digest was the same with or without null at the end